# How can I reference/find the ${PV} of one recipe in another recipe in Yocto/Bitbake?

Tags: python, linux, yocto, bitbake

I have a recipe that needs to know the version string/information of another recipe. Basically I want to expand the PV variable of a different recipe. What would be the easiest way to do this? I was thinking maybe there is a bb python function I can use in my recipe to parse the other recipe and find it's PV.

Answer (score 0):

Easily, you can't. Can you explain what you actually need to do?

Comment: I am using a specific class which generates a kind of compound image of other bitbake generated image files. I wanted to store some specific information regarding the "versions" of the recipes (which generate the image files) from those files in a text file (which will be utilized at runtime for something else later).