# How can I make a yocto layer compatible with different releases that come with incompatible lib versions

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I have a layer with recipes that is compatible with rocko. I'd like to add compatibility for thud. `LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_layer` supports a **list**, so supporting more than one release with a layer seems to be intended.

Thud contains some version bumps to libraries that break compatibility. An example would be protobuf-3.6, which contains incompatible API changes to the earlier version used in rocko.

For all packages in the layer, I have patches for their sources that make them compatible with the new API versions (only).

Currently, there is a culture of creating different branches (or even forks) of meta-layers in order to support different library versions. This causes heavy fragmentation and deviation between the projects and departments.

If I can create recipes that work independent of, for example, the exact version of protobuf used in a build, then I can merge back some of those forks and branches and maintain **one** repo.

- I tried some approach with conditional `.bbappend`, but couldn't find a way to do it. There seems to be no equivalent for COMPATIBLE_MACHINE, for example, that I could use to differentiate between releases.
- I also tried an approach of conditionally patching the sources depending on actual PV of a dependency. Basically trying to do what is described in the following snipped of recipe pseudo code:

```
DEPENDS += "protobuf"
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/foo/bar;"

if ${protobuf_PV} larger_or_equal "3.6.0"
  SRC_URI_append = " file://replace_protobuf_scoped_ptr.patch"
endif
```

I found an existing answer here which made me doubt that this is possible: [How can I reference/find the ${PV} of one recipe in another recipe in Yocto/Bitbake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56794981)

So, what mechanisms, if any, does bitbake provide to help me make a recipe compatible with different versions of dependencies in general, and with different yocto releases in particular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed use multiple compatible versions in LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_layer, see [here](https://github.com/sbabic/meta-swupdate/blob/master/conf/layer.conf) for example. It's what Poky do when `master` branch becomes a new version, and set compatibity for current and next simultaneously.

Generally, we use same branching model as Yocto meta layers, so one branch for `rocko`and one branch for `thud`.

In your case, what you can do is having a small layer with Yocto branching model, that will only configure [PREFERRED_VERSION](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-PREFERRED_VERSION) for recipes that are different between `rocko` and `thud`, and another global layer with every recipes. You can also create two distros for each Yocto version and use overrides.

Finally you can try the following pattern:

```
SRC_URI += "${@bb.utils.contains("DISTRO_CODENAME", "thud", " file://replace_protobuf_scoped_ptr.patch ", "", d)}"
```

Comment: Thanks :). I accepted this answer, since the proposed pattern solves at least the particular case where different library versions are caused by different yocto releases. I still have no solution for the more generic case of supporting different library versions no matter where they are coming from. But I have a feeling what I am trying to do there is just not currently possible.